# nextjs serve application from custom build folder

Tags: next.js

I have added custom build folder for nextjs build
https://nextjsorg.now.sh/docs/#setting-a-custom-build-directory
after running "next start" command I want to serve app from custom build folder.by default it will look for _next folder.
how to serve app from custom build folder